# How to give two thumbs for UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can we get the range between two thumbs in `UISlider`. My application contains price range selection i didn't get with a single thumb. Here i need to show the range on labels above the thumbs also these labels are inside the images.

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30589205/775896

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We cannot give two thumbs for one slider because we cannot change UI But we can give With our own design. For that first we have to take two buttons and two UIViews We need to change the buttons positions according to user touch and also change UI widths based on buttons positions. We have have a third party frame works like `NMRangeSlider` and `VPRangeSlider`.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a filter without pods just for curious with next API:

```
let slider = DoubledSlider()
slider.minimumValue = 0
slider.maximumValue = 100
```

To fetch `UIEvent.valueChanged` simply do this:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didChangeSliderValue), for: .valueChanged)
```

And finally handle values like below:

```
@objc private func didChangeSliderValue() {
    print(self.slider.values.minimum)
    print(self.slider.values.maximum)
}
```

And this looks like

[image]

You can customize API, UI or whatever. All code source is [open](https://gist.github.com/mcsh0k/169e20dd0b8d45be6d2cfd9aa36b2e23). Enjoy.

Comment: Hi @shokuroff , I am trying to use this but can you tell me what is `FeedbackManager.shared.vibrate()` is for ?

Comment: @SaadUllah hi, check [here](https://gist.github.com/shokuroff/933fd8001cc590db6bf9617cd4c0f51b)! This class is responsible on calling vibration on device when it needs. You can implement you own implementation or hust use this class in the reference (gist).

Comment: how to set a default value for the slider?

Answer (score 3):

Based on shokuroff's answer, I have updated this double slider into the following version. It gives the following improvements (at least for me):

- Based on SnapKit
- I can use bigger Thumb image. Especially ones with shadows. The original code some how rely on thumb image size. [Thumb Image I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mazgT.png)
- Thumbs can be a little outside the progress bar's frame. Like UISlider does.

[UISlider and this DoubleSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqY07.jpg)

Here's the code:

```
import SnapKit
import UIKit

public final class DoubledSlider: UIControl {
    public struct Constant {
        let height: CGFloat = 4.0
        let trackForegroundImage: UIImage = // Use an image for your progress bar
        let thumbWrapperSize: CGFloat = 31.0
        let thumbSize: CGFloat = 56.0
        let miniThumbDistance: CGFloat = 5.0
        let edgeMakeup: CGFloat = 5.0
    }

    private let constants = Constant()
    var trackBackgroundColor: UIColor {
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        // swiftlint:disable force_unwrapping
        return UIColor(hexString: "333333")!
        } else {
        // swiftlint:disable force_unwrapping
        return UIColor(hexString: "#DDDDDD")!
        }
    }

    private lazy var track = UIView()
    private lazy var activeTrack = UIImageView()
    private lazy var leftThumbWrapper = UIImageView()
    private lazy var rightThumbWrapper = UIImageView()
    private lazy var leftThumb = UIImageView(image: /* Your Image with shadows. */)
    private lazy var rightThumb = UIImageView(image: /* Your Image with shadows. */)

    // MARK: - Initialization

    public convenience init(minimumValue: Float = .zero, maximumValue: Float = .zero) {
        self.init()
        self.minimumValue = minimumValue
        self.maximumValue = maximumValue
    }

    private override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Setup UI

    private func setupUI() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        clipsToBounds = false
        setupTrack()
        setupThumb()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupTrack() {
        addSubview(track)
        activeTrack = UIImageView(image: constants.trackForegroundImage)
        track.addSubview(activeTrack)
        track.layer.masksToBounds = true
        track.layer.cornerRadius = constants.height / 2
        track.backgroundColor = trackBackgroundColor
        track.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    private func setupThumb() {
        addSubview(leftThumbWrapper)
        addSubview(rightThumbWrapper)
        leftThumbWrapper.addSubview(leftThumb)
        rightThumbWrapper.addSubview(rightThumb)
        [leftThumbWrapper, rightThumbWrapper].forEach {
        $0.clipsToBounds = false
        $0.contentMode = .center
        $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dragThumb(using:)))
        $0.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
        [leftThumb, rightThumb].forEach {
        $0.clipsToBounds = false
        $0.contentMode = .center
        }
        self.leftThumbWrapper.tag = 1
        self.rightThumbWrapper.tag = 2
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        track.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(constants.height)
        }

        leftThumbWrapper.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.size.equalTo(constants.thumbWrapperSize)
        make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        leftThumbConstraint = make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(-constants.edgeMakeup).constraint
        make.right.lessThanOrEqualTo(rightThumbWrapper)
        }

        rightThumbWrapper.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.size.equalTo(constants.thumbWrapperSize)
        make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        rightThumbConstraint = make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            .offset(constants.edgeMakeup)
            .constraint
        make.left.greaterThanOrEqualTo(leftThumbWrapper)
        }

        leftThumb.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.size.equalTo(constants.thumbSize)
        make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }

        rightThumb.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.size.equalTo(constants.thumbSize)
        make.center.equalToSuperview()
        }

        activeTrack.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        leftActiveTrackConstraint = make.leading.equalToSuperview()
            .offset(-constants.edgeMakeup)
            .constraint
        rightActiveTrackConstraint = make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            .offset(constants.edgeMakeup)
            .constraint
        make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        make.height.equalTo(constants.height)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Drag

    @objc private func dragThumb(using gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let view = gesture.view else { return }
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self)
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
        if [1, 2].contains(view.tag) { bringSubviewToFront(view) }

        case .changed:
        self.handleDragging(view, withTranslation: translation)

        case .ended:
        self.handleEndedDragging(view)

        default:
        break
        }
    }

    private func handleDragging(_ view: UIView, withTranslation translation: CGPoint) {
        switch view.tag {
        case 1:
        handleDraggingLeftThumb(view, withTranslation: translation)

        case 2:
        handleDraggingRightThumb(view, withTranslation: translation)

        default:
        break
        }
    }

    private func handleDraggingLeftThumb(_ thumb: UIView, withTranslation translation: CGPoint) {
        let newConstant = translation.x + self.leftThumbConstraintLastConstant
        guard newConstant >= -constants.edgeMakeup else {
        leftThumbWrapper.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(-constants.edgeMakeup)
        }
        activeTrack.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(-constants.edgeMakeup)
        }
        self.updateValues {
            self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
        return
        }
        if thumbesInOnePlace(byDraggingThumb: thumb) && translation.x > .zero { return }
        leftThumbWrapper.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant)
        }
        activeTrack.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant + constants.edgeMakeup)
        }
        self.updateValues {
        self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }

    private func handleDraggingRightThumb(_ thumb: UIView, withTranslation translation: CGPoint) {
        let newConstant = translation.x + rightThumbConstraintLastConstant
        guard newConstant <= constants.edgeMakeup else {
        rightThumbWrapper.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(constants.edgeMakeup)
        }
        activeTrack.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(constants.edgeMakeup)
        }
        self.updateValues {
            self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
        return
        }
        if thumbesInOnePlace(byDraggingThumb: thumb) && translation.x < .zero { return }
        rightThumbWrapper.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant)
        }
        activeTrack.snp.updateConstraints { make in
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant - constants.edgeMakeup)
        }
        self.updateValues {
        self.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }

    private func handleEndedDragging(_ view: UIView) {
        switch view.tag {
        case 1:
        leftThumbConstraintLastConstant = leftThumbConstant
        leftActiveTrackConstraintLastConstant = leftActiveTrackConstant

        case 2:
        rightThumbConstraintLastConstant = rightThumbConstant
        rightActiveTrackConstraintLastConstant = rightActiveTrackConstant

        default:
        break
        }
    }

    private func thumbesInOnePlace(byDraggingThumb thumb: UIView) -> Bool {
        let difference = abs(self.leftThumbWrapper.center.x - self.rightThumbWrapper.center.x)
        let onePlace = difference < constants.miniThumbDistance
        if onePlace {
        forceThumbsPositions(byActiveThumb: thumb)
        }
        return onePlace
    }

    private func forceThumbsPositions(byActiveThumb thumb: UIView) {
        switch thumb.tag {
        case 1:
        let newConstant = rightThumbWrapper.frame.origin.x
        leftThumbWrapper.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant)
        }
        leftThumbConstraintLastConstant = newConstant
        activeTrack.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant)
        }
        leftActiveTrackConstraintLastConstant = newConstant

        case 2:
        let centerXDifference = rightThumbWrapper.center.x - leftThumbWrapper.center.x
        let newConstant = rightThumbConstant - centerXDifference
        rightThumbWrapper.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant)
        }
        rightThumbConstraintLastConstant = newConstant
        activeTrack.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(newConstant)
        }
        rightActiveTrackConstraintLastConstant = newConstant

        default:
        break
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Constraints as value

    private var leftThumbConstraint: Constraint?
    private var rightThumbConstraint: Constraint?

    private var leftThumbConstant: CGFloat {
        return leftThumbConstraint?.layoutConstraints[0].constant ?? 0
    }

    private var rightThumbConstant: CGFloat {
        return rightThumbConstraint?.layoutConstraints[0].constant ?? 0
    }

    private var leftThumbConstraintLastConstant: CGFloat = .zero
    private var rightThumbConstraintLastConstant: CGFloat = .zero

    private var leftActiveTrackConstraint: Constraint?
    private var rightActiveTrackConstraint: Constraint?

    private var leftActiveTrackConstant: CGFloat {
        return leftActiveTrackConstraint?.layoutConstraints[0].constant ?? 0
    }

    private var rightActiveTrackConstant: CGFloat {
        return rightActiveTrackConstraint?.layoutConstraints[0].constant ?? 0
    }

    private var leftActiveTrackConstraintLastConstant: CGFloat = .zero
    private var rightActiveTrackConstraintLastConstant: CGFloat = .zero

    // MARK: - Public API

    public var minimumValue: Float = .zero
    public var maximumValue: Float = .zero

    public var values: (minimum: Float, maximum: Float) {
        get { return (minimumValueNow, maximumValueNow) }
        set {
        var newMin: Float = .zero
        var newMax: Float = .zero
        if newValue.0 <= .zero {
            newMin = minimumValue
        }
        if newValue.0 <= minimumValue {
            newMin = minimumValue
        }
        if newValue.0 > newValue.1 {
            newMin = newValue.1
        }
        if newValue.1 <= .zero {
            newMax = minimumValue
        }
        if newValue.1 >= maximumValue {
            newMax = maximumValue
        }
        if newValue.1 < newValue.0 {
            newMax = newValue.0
        }
        self.minimumValueNow = newMin
        self.maximumValueNow = newMax
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private API

    private var minimumValueNow: Float = .zero
    private var maximumValueNow: Float = .zero

    private func updateValues(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        minimumValueNow = newMinimalValue
        maximumValueNow = newMaximumValue
        let originXDifference = abs(rightThumbWrapper.frame.origin.x - leftThumbWrapper.frame.origin.x)
        if originXDifference < constants.miniThumbDistance {
        if minimumValueNow == minimumValue {
            maximumValueNow = minimumValueNow
        } else {
            minimumValueNow = maximumValueNow
        }
        }
        completion()
    }

    private var newMinimalValue: Float {
        let leftThumbOriginX = leftThumbConstant
        let distancePassed = leftThumbOriginX + constants.edgeMakeup
        let totalDistance = track.frame.size.width +
        2 * constants.edgeMakeup -
        constants.thumbWrapperSize
        let distancePassedFraction = distancePassed / totalDistance
        if leftThumbOriginX <= -constants.edgeMakeup {
        return minimumValue
        }
        if distancePassed > totalDistance {
        return maximumValue
        }
        let newValue: Float = {
        let difference = maximumValue - minimumValue
        let addingValue = Float(distancePassedFraction) * difference
        return minimumValue + addingValue
        }()
        return newValue
    }

    private var newMaximumValue: Float {
        let constraintConstant = rightThumbConstant
        let distancePassed = abs(constraintConstant - constants.edgeMakeup)
        let totalDistance = track.frame.size.width +
        2 * constants.edgeMakeup -
        constants.thumbWrapperSize
        let distancePassedFraction = distancePassed / totalDistance
        if constraintConstant >= constants.edgeMakeup {
        return maximumValue
        }
        if distancePassed > totalDistance {
        return self.minimumValue
        }
        let newValue: Float = {
        let difference = maximumValue - minimumValue
        let addingValue = difference * Float(distancePassedFraction)
        return maximumValue - addingValue
        }()

        return newValue
    }
}
```