# SWIFT | How to get start time and end time from user?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, timepicker

i have an app and i have made a custom mode for the user ( similar to do not disturb mode ).
I want the user to be able to set the start time and end time of that mode manually ( either by picker or slider ) along with AM/PM mode or 24 hour format but it is not possible.

I thought i could achieve this with datepicker time mode but i do not want to present two textfield.

the counter version for this on android looks something like the image below. The UI is not important to me but only the functionality is.

Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction ?!

Any help is appreciated.

date picker method will need two fields as i mentioned with is a problem. also the problem with date picker is that it should not look like a textfield so i prefer a UIBUTTON so i can set the image for the button.[image: something like this functionality]

Comment: Try something like [this](https://github.com/joedaniels29/10Clock)?

Comment: i did but the weirdest things happened that is, the module cannot be imported. This issue could not be resolved, i tried re install, remove and again, restart xcode. All other third party works flawless but this one just would not import so i assumed it was an issue.

Comment: I'd like to recommend a [range slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588783/how-to-create-range-slider-programmatically-in-ios). There's some examples in that post. You could try to have it slide from 0-24 or 0-12 depending on a checkbox for AM/PM or a 24h clock. You could then parse the slider range to a certain timespan or start and end time. Hope this helps!